# Does it works Calling Multiple asynchronous function of RIA Service parallelly

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I'm Using SIlverlight 4.0 application with MVVM Architecture using RIA Service 
 I'm Calling Multiple Asynchronous Function of RIA Service which provides me the list of different Entities in the same View Model initially it was not giving any problems but now i m getting error such as "**The type 'TFM.Entities.Type' has been mapped more than once.**
can u suggest me any Solution to avoid this type of error.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You error seems to came from entity framework not from ria services. How do you instantiate your ObjectContext ? 
One possible reason is that you try to instantiate an additonal ObjectContext from within the DomainService class, in that case remember that the base class already instantiate one for you.

Comment: Yup My error was due to the domain service which i added in before giving the base entity ref. so i removed it and it is working fine now. :)